# How do I permanently change the hostname on Solaris 10?

Tags: solaris

I want to permanently change the hostname on a Solaris box.  How do I do that?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Assuming that you have allowed the operating system to configure the primary interface for you, there are three (3) files you must change:

```
/etc/hosts
/etc/nodename
/etc/hostname.<interface>
```

<interface> will be the primary ethernet interface for the system.  Some examples (depending on your architecture) will be bge0, hme0, e1000g0, eri0, qfe0. Here's an ad-free answer for future reference.

Also change the savecore directory to reflect the new hostname in `/etc/dumpadm.conf`, and you may also need to edit `/etc/inet/ipnodes`, depending on the exact version of Solaris.

Comment: It's important to mention here, as per RealAdmin's answer that the savecore directory /var/crash/<hostname> and dumpadm configuration should be changed too when changing the hostname.

Answer (score 2):

They don't make it easy, do they?

Answer here: http://www.tech-faq.com/change-hostname-solaris.shtml

Comment: Thanks! I actually got to that page from Google, but my eyes totally missed the answer due to the rampant ads.

Answer (score 2):

The supported way of doing this is to run the *sys-unconfig* command, then reconfigure the host with the desired name.

Answer (score 2):

to piggyback off gary chambers--here's a more authoritative source!  His answer is correct though, I give him all the credit for that, but I take a Reaganistic approach to external sources...trust--but verify!

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/816-4554/gbwxb/index.html

section 5.1: Modifying the IPv4 Address and Other Network Parameters to Persist Across Reboots

taken from:   System Administration Guide: IP Services  > Part II TCP/IP Administration  > Chapter 5 Configuring TCP/IP Network Services and IPv4 Addressing (Tasks)  > Configuring Systems on the Local Network  > How to Change the IPv4 Address and Other Network Configuration Parameters

**Also in versions earlier than 11/06, do the following:**

**# vi /etc/inet/ipnodes**

<*IPoflocalhost*>   <*updatedhostname*>

Answer (score 1):

sys-unconfig may be the supported way of doing this, but it completely hoses the entire configuration of the machine and you have to re-configure a reboot (from the LOM or system controller).  What a pain.

also issue the command hostname new_hostname and a reboot is not required.  You must also rename the /var/cras/hostname file and update the /etc/dumpadm.conf file and change the hostname.

Answer (score 1):

Use: 
 **uname -S <new-hostname>**  
to change the hostname of a running system. Beware that the change will be lost upon reboot. To make them permanent, modify the files indicated by Gary Chambers.

Answer (score -1):

```
#ifconfig -a

lo: 127.0.0.1  e1000g0 : 192.168.1.2 <----- Ur interface Name

#vi /etc/hostname.<interface>
192.168.1.2 hostname hostname
```

save and exit

```
#svcadm restart network
```